Flutter Android Phone Sign In Crash
My Flutter app is crashing when the Firebase code is sent after trying to sign in with a phone number for Android user.
Exception java.lang.RuntimeException:
  at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.lambda$getRunnable$0 (LoadedApk.java:1919)
  at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.$r8$lambda$gDuJqgxY6Zb-ifyeubKeivTLAwk
  at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:958)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:99)
  at android.os.Looper.loopOnce (Looper.java:230)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:319)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:8919)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:578)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1103)
Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.lang.CharSequence.length()' on a null object reference
  at java.util.regex.Matcher.reset (Matcher.java:386)
  at java.util.regex.Matcher.<init> (Matcher.java:210)
  at java.util.regex.Pattern.matcher (Pattern.java:989)
  at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzadt.zza (com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@22.3.1:3)
  at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzadx.onReceive (com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@22.3.1)
  at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.lambda$getRunnable$0 (LoadedApk.java:1911)

if i try to sign in on a different phone where it wont sent the code it works fine.
